# Hovering over a drop-down list ends all :hover states in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Take a look at this little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TnzS4/

Open up the SELECT box, and hover its the drop-down list.

In Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera, the box is red, which means that the `:hover` state is still active.

In IE, the box is gray, which means that the `:hover` state is inactive.

Is this an IE bug?

**Edit:** Please open the above page in your version of IE and report (via a comment) whether you have this behavior or not.

Comment: What version of internet explorer are you using?

Comment: It works fine for me in IE 7, so must be something new with IE 9

Comment: Could someone check how IE8 behaves?

Comment: @Šime: IE8 works fine. No problems at all.

Comment: It seems that I found a IE9 bug. :)

Comment: @Šime: Actually I just tested this on the latest [IE9 platform preview](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/info/downloads/Default.html) and it seems to work. So while you did find a bug (nice one ;-), it seems they've found it too and fixed it. This whole exchange does highlight, however, how silly Microsoft's release cycles are. In the amount of time since the IE team have released their last beta IE9, Chrome has incremented 2 versions.

Comment: @treeface Good that they fixed it :) My theory why the IE releases are so slow is: IE is deeply integrated into the OS. It's not a simple, independent 10MB application, but part of the Windows OS.

Comment: @Šime: Well, a simple application Chrome is not. Chrome's bug reporting and user participation is one of the big reasons things get done so quickly. I've also heard lots of stories about how the management team for IE has (historically) been a bit less than forward-thinking. IE could adopt a channel-based release system like Chrome, but instead they opt for the closed-source, long update cycles which (in theory) protect their product from being duplicated. The joke is that nobody in their right mind would steal IE's source when Chromium, Firefox, and Opera exist.

Comment: @JMC @Šime: I've updated my answer with bad news.

Answer (score 1):

I might as well turn this into an answer since I can't really close this given that it's an entirely valid question. As Andrew Sehr discovered, this problem doesn't seem to happen in IE<=7. I confirmed that it doesn't happen in IE8, and then I found that it doesn't happen in the latest release of the IE9 platform preview. As such, I think we can chalk this one up to a temporary bug in the IE9 beta channel (though it's hard to call something a "channel" when the last release was nearly 3 months ago).

Nice find, Šime.

---

**Edit**: The first time I read this question, I completely missed the part about how you're first supposed to open the select box, then hover over the options. When this happens, it seems all versions of IE (including IE9's latest platform preview) does not consider the `div` underneath to be in a `:hover` state. This is all down to the way IE still handles events in a `select` element. The sad fact of the matter is that there is no pure CSS way to get around this. You'll need to manipulate events in JavaScript.

The bad news is that this will only get you part of the way there. Consider this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TnzS4/5/

```
$('#wrap > select').focus(function() {
    $('#wrap').addClass('wrap_hover');
}).blur(function() {
    $('#wrap').removeClass('wrap_hover');
});
```

Here you're not losing the `:hover` when you hover over the `option` elements, but you also aren't dropping the `:hover` when you mouseout of the `#wrap` element. If this behavior is unacceptable to you, then you won't be happy to know that you'll have to test for IE in your JS because otherwise this code will duplicate the behavior in all browsers.

So I suppose this is what a dead end looks like. If I were you, I'd either ignore the issue (if anybody ever complained I'd tell them to not use a shit browser) or I'd get rid of the `:hover` effect and find another way to reach whatever UI goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: check it out, I had almost the exact same solution yesterday to my original problem that spawned this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586396/keep-divhover-open-when-changing-nested-select-box/4587962#4587962

Comment: how about `<!--[if IE]><h1 style="font-size:19em;">You Seem to be Using a Shit-Browser</h1><[endif]-->` at the top of the page? That'd solve it.

Comment: @JMC: Nice one ;-]. Yeh, I can't seem to think of a better way to do this. If I'm not incorrect, there *is* no better way to do it. Of course you can use `[if IE]` tags...I should have said that instead of "test for IE in your JS".

Answer (score 1):

I still see this problem.  I am using IE 8, and the problem is there. @treeface, are you using build 8.0.6001.18702 ? @Šime, you don't see the problem anymore in IE8?

I was the one who originaly brought this to Šime's attention, and as such, I'd like to re-open this question, to perhaps find out why *my* Internet Explorer is having this issue, while it seems that noone else's is?

So *really*, you all are not having this issue?

According to my IE Developer bar, this problem exists for me in Browser Mode: IE8, IE7, and IE8 Compatibility view.  Also tested with the different Document Modes(IE7 Standards, IE8 Standards, Quirks Mode), but all give the same bug.

Comment: I only have IE9 beta here (9.0.7930.16406).

Comment: Thanks for reopening @Šime, maybe we'll get some more input.

Comment: Sorry I actually totally misread the question the first time around. It looks like this is indeed something that happens in IE only. It happens in IE8 *and* the IE9 platform preview. I'm updating my answer right now.