# Containing div loses focus when mousing over select dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a div that appears when you hover over its container and the div is positioned absolutely, so that it appears outside of its container. It has multiple select dropdowns within it, and when I try to change the value of any of them, the focus is lost it triggers a mouseout on the container.

I've set up a working example of this issue here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uBjR3/2/

This issue is occurring in FireFox and IE (Chrome seems to work fine).

=====

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select>
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>
            <option>option 3</option>
            <option>option 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { background-color: red; height: 30px; width: 60px; padding: 20px; position: relative; }

.dropdown { background-color: blue; height: 300px; width: 200px; padding: 20px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 0px; display: none; }
```

JQuery:

```
$('.container').hover(
  function () {
    $('.dropdown').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: linking related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586396/keep-divhover-open-when-changing-nested-select-box

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at your code. Replace your jQuery with this and it will work as you wish

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.container').hover(function(){
      $('.dropdown').stop(1).slideDown();
   },function(){
      $(".dropdown").stop(1).slideUp();
   }); 

});
```

here's the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/uBjR3/11/

Comment: I'd say that's more handy for this use case than my solution :)

Comment: So this looks like it works - thanks! An alternative solution which I just implemented and came here to post, was to use no jquery at all and control the show/hide of the .dropdown div with css (I don't know why it took me so long to figure that out).

Comment: Actually, this solution is not really working in IE9. It does solve the issue in Firefox though

Comment: An option would be to put an "if" statement around it and apply it to Firefox only

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timeout to prevent the hide action. Something like:

```
var timer;
$('PARENT')
    .on(
        mouseenter: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('.dropdown').show();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.dropdown').hide();
            }, 400);
        }, '.container')
    .on(
        mouseenter: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.dropdown').hide();
            }, 400);
        }, '.dropdown');
```