# Input select dropdown not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am facing a input select dropdown problem in Firefox browser but it works fine in Google Chrome.

I have created a jQuery submenu box. My problem is when I put content in the content area of the submenu, its ok. But when I am creating a select box in that content area its not working in Firefox but works fine chrome browser...I mean I can't select any option of that select box when I am trying to select option 2, option 3 etc, the whole thing got disappear.

I need your help regarding this.

Here is my **html** code:

```
<div class="layout_nemo" style="margin:0px auto; width:520px;">
    <aside id="models">
        <section class="nestingList" style="width:520px;">
            <div style="float:right; width:100px; border:1px solid #f00; text-align:right"><a href="#" class="track-click">A5</a>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both; margin:0px; padding:0px;"></div>
            <div class="flyout" style="border:3px solid #000;">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="col" style="float:right;">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="#" class="track-click">A5 Coupé</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="track-click">A5 Sportback</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="articles" style="float:left;">
                        <article class="visuallyhidden">
                            <select name="bvgn " style="border:1px solid #000; height:30px;width:180px;">
                                <option>option1</option>
                                <option>option2</option>
                                <option>option3</option>
                                <option>option4</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="bvgn " style="border:1px solid #000; height:30px;width:180px;">
                                <option>option5</option>
                                <option>option6</option>
                                <option>option7</option>
                                <option>option8</option>
                            </select>
                        </article>
                        <article class="visuallyhidden" style="border:7px solid #3C0; height:30px;">content here</article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
```

And the **CSS** code:

```
.visuallyhidden {
    border:0;
    clip:rect(0 0 0 0);
    height:1px;
    margin:-1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
}
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active, .visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
clip:auto;
height:auto;
margin:0;
overflow:visible;
position:static;
width:auto;
}
.clearfix:after, .layout_nemo .nemo_carousel .pagination:after {
clear:both;
}
aside {
display:block;
}
nav ul, ul.nav {
padding-bottom:0;
}
.flyout {
display:none;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
z-index:9999;
}
.flyout nav#navigation .links a {
font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:20px;
font-weight:bold;
background-position:0 -444px;
}
.flyout nav#navigation .links a:hover {
background-position:0 -444px;
}
.flyout>.inner {
position:relative;
margin:-3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
#models {
position:absolute;
top:-124px;
}
#models.home {
top:-84px;
}
#models section {
display:inline;
float:left;
}
#models .flyout {
left:-3px;
width:520px;
}
#models .articles, #models .inner {
overflow:hidden;
}
#models .inner {
position:relative;
padding-top:20px;
min-height:280px;
}
#models .nav li {
list-style-image:none;
list-style-type:none;
margin-left:0;
}
#models .nav a {
display:block;
height:29px;
line-height:29px;
padding-left:9px;
border-top:1px solid #e7e9ea;
text-decoration:none;
background:none;
}
body.special #main .content .mediaContainer, body.special #main .content .audi_flash_replace, body.special #main .content .flash_3col, body.special #main .content .con_flashfilm_3col, body.special #main .content body.special.detail .headline h1 {
font-size:36px;
}
.layout_nemo #models {
top:23px;
}
.layout_nemo #models section>h1>a {
margin-left:0;
}
```

Also sharing you a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/indy12/cgRA2/13/)
 where we have tried the whole thing includes all the js files. Please have a look of that link in both browser (firefox & chrome)

Comment: Looks like a Firefox specific bug, where drop down items are not part of their parent element so the `onmouseout` is triggered. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there any other way to sort it out like adding some jquery fucntion or something?I really need this to be sorted out :)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is using custom drop down, which use "regular" elements to mimic drop down list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can you show it in an example? It will be really helpful for me :)

Comment: There is the "native" jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin that has custom drop down as well. See [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have tried it with your given example..but it shows the same results when I put it in my code..Firefox issue is still there...

Comment: Weird... I'm at a loss then, sorry.

Comment: @indy - if you build a proper nested HTML / CSS menu rather than hacking together some HTML and Javascript then you won't have a problem. I had a "play" with your code, removed the javascript links and added some hacky CSS - it isn't a working solution, it just demonstrates you would not have a problem with your `input` fields: http://jsfiddle.net/cgRA2/14/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for your effort though..much appreciate of it..I might be doing some mistake while implementing the code...I really don't know...It would be great if you have time then you can do similar kind of thing and put in somewhere like jsfiddle then I would be really grateful to you..there has to be a way :(

Comment: @indy if you ask me, better start from scratch. That menu isn't working very well to begin with, even in Chrome.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am feeling the same..Actually this whole code is a very small part of a big project. So my options are like very limited. I just can't start from scratch. I have to go along with all the given CSS and JS. Or else making a standard dropdown won't be much difficult for me..If I can't do this with the given CSS and JS then I might give up the whole issue. Nevertheless thank you again for your effort and time :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Thank you for your effort :) I really know the whole HTML and javascript isn't in a very good shape...but you really worked hard to sort that out...so thank you once again :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I don't why your given link not working in Chrome but works almost perfectly on Firefox...can you take a look at that?

Comment: @indy - it does not work in Chrome because webkit has bugs with chained CSS selectors - it is also not implemented to work in the way that you want as it is not possible with your current HTML structure. The purpose of my JSFiddle was to demonstrate that if you take the time to rebuild your HTML and CSS correctly then you will not have the problem you are having now.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Ok..I understand your point...I am working with it now..Problem is that I have to work with the given CSS and HTML structure..And since you have almost solved the problem without using any JS files, so I think I can work with your code and fix the remaining issue.

Answer (score 2):

Developing primarily in Chrome will always lead to strange behavior in other browsers, so a good start would be to do it in Firefox. If it works in Firefox 99% it will work everywhere else, in IE too. Chrome has a lot of assumptions and "helpful" features that derail developers.

Also, my test in Firefox showed no errors. I am using 23.0.1.

Comment: Can you show me your test because I am using 23.0.1 too but it shows error?

Comment: Your html/css code looks like crap. I'm debugging it now. I will post results once I tidy everything up. I need few minutes.

Comment: U just refactored entire HTML code and started working on CSS. This effect and everything concerned around the dropdown is not happening inside HTML/CSS, so you must be using some external JavaScript to do this.

Comment: I know all the html/css code are for no good. And that's why I posted my code in here. So that I can get some help. If you can do similar kind of thing using some other html/css structure then I don't have any problem. And yes I have used few external javascript to do this. And here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/indy12/cgRA2/13/)
 of that. On that page (left hand side), under External Resources tab I have put my external javascript.

Comment: @indy I get you man, but boy... Was that code messy. And its hard to refactor something that you dont have a full picture of. I'm not trying to blow smoke up your arse but to help you, and in order do to that I first must understand what is going on.

After I took apart the code I realized that the code itself is not the reason why your option/select is causing problems in Firefox.

I strongly suggest you take a moment and re asses the project and the way its done. Right now, cramming together all that JS into one file, its not good from the point of developing.

Answer (score 1):

I just refactored entire HTML code and started working on CSS. I've done this up to now I hope it helps, somewhat.

http://jsfiddle.net/cgRA2/19/

```
<div class="layout_nemo">
<aside id="models">         
    <section class="nestingList">
        <div id="new_url_top">
            <a href="#" class="track-click">A5 series</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both; margin:0px; padding:0px;"></div>
        <div class="flyout" style="border:3px solid #000;">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="col" style="float:right;">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#" class="track-click">A5 Coupé</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="track-click" >A5 Sportback</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="articles" style="float:left;">
                    <article class="visuallyhidden">
                        <select name="bvgn " style="border:1px solid #000; height:30px;width:180px;">
                            <option>option1</option>
                            <option>option2</option>
                            <option>option3</option>
                            <option>option4</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="bvgn " style="border:1px solid #000; height:30px;width:180px;">
                            <option>option5</option>
                            <option>option6</option>
                            <option>option7</option>
                            <option>option8</option>
                        </select>
                    </article>
                    <article class="visuallyhidden" style="border:7px solid #3C0; height:30px;">content here</article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</aside>
```

The effect and everything concerned around the dropdown is not happening inside HTML/CSS, and its not Firefox problem because of that. I thought you must have been using some external JavaScript to do this, and I was right.

Problem is inside your **js.js** file, that you have included into external files for the jsFiddle example page. One part of the problem is that the file is combined with everything else and is part of something much bigger. I would really hate going into it after doing html/css.

So the part of jQuery that is making the problem is located around:

- line 4836
- line 4841
- line 4937
- line 4942
- line 5074

If you can get that spaghetti code out and do something with it... Good luck.

Someone posted a solution here [Containing div loses focus when mousing over select dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749315/containing-div-loses-focus-when-mousing-over-select-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

July 14, 2021

Anyone experiencing recent issues with Firefox not rendering HTML, in particular the `<select>` element correctly see below:

I have been managing a Grails web application for a number of years and came across this issue just the other day, where my site worked fine in all browsers, but for whatever strange reason, Firefox simply would *not* render the `<select>` tags in their allocated `<div>`

Following a lot of testing across the browsers and using Firebug console/inspection, I tracked it down to an old HTML 4.0 Doctype definition.

As soon as I updated my site to the HTML 5 standard doctype, Firefox fell into line and rendered everything perfectly.

FIX:

Change OLD Doctype:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">`

To NEW Doctype:
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

I know this is YEARS later than the original question post, but I would have really appreciated stumbling across this answer.

I hope it helps someone out there.